# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit' and NameError

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program in which if I enter a positive number then it executes further but if I enter a negative number or a letter it should print 'House price must be a positive number' and it should ask for the input again. This is what I've done so far but when I enter an number I get an `AttributeError` and when I enter a letter I get a `NameError`.

```
import math

while True:
    home_price = input('Enter the price of your dreams house')
    if home_price.isdigit():
        if home_price > 0:    
            home_price = int(house_price)
            break
        else:
            print('House price must be a positive number only')
```

Comment: Your code here is a mess. Where is your declaration of `house_price`?

Comment: @AK47 the declaration is `home_price = input('Enter the price of your dreams house')`. It's valid here.

Comment: @C._ but what about line 7? - Also the code has been updated since I left that original comment ( formatting / indentation was completely messed up )

Comment: @AK47 Yes, I agree that the redecleration is sort of messed up. But the 1st one is fine.

Comment: but the redeclaration uses the variable `house_price`, which is undefined in this code........................................

Comment: @AK47 I said that *only* the 1st one was correct. The rest of the code is dependent on the assumption that `home_price` is *always* an int, which it isn't. It's also somewhat mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 2, whose [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) function does an `eval(..)` on the user input, and `eval("2")` returns an `int`, not a `str`.

```
python2 -c 'print(eval("2").__class__)'
<type 'int'>
```

Your code will work on Python 2 if you replace `input` with `raw_input`, which doesnt do an `eval`.

Comment: I'm using python 3, and i don't why it always gives me a NameError when i enter something other than a number

Comment: Your name error is because you're doing `int(house_price)` when your variable is called `home_price`.. as for int has no method `.isdigit()`, this is because there's no reason to check if `1.isdigit()`, because it obviously is. The `isdigit()` method is part of the string class

Comment: If you were using Python 3, the outcome would be `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your loop running until you receive a positive integer, you can just test for negative integers / non digit values entered and then continue to the next iteration. Otherwise you can just break from your loop

```
while True:
    home_price = input('Enter the price of your dream house: ')

    if not home_price.isdigit() or not int(home_price) > 0:
        print('House price must be a positive integer only')
        continue

    print('The price of your dream house is: %s' % home_price)
    break

Enter the price of your dream house: a
House price must be a positive integer only
Enter the price of your dream house: -1
House price must be a positive integer only
Enter the price of your dream house: 1000
The price of your dream house is: 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend exception handling. "-10".isdigit() returns false.

```
import math

while True:
    home_price = input('Enter the price of your dreams house')
    try:
        if int(home_price) > 0:    
            house_price = int(home_price)
            break
        else:
            print('House price must be a positive number only')
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

Comment: I'm sorry to ask again, but i still keep getting a NameError when i enter any alphabets

Comment: NameError  "Raised when a local or global name is not found. This applies only to unqualified names. The associated value is an error message that includes the name that could not be found." Did you also correct your variable assignment for house_price? In your original code the assignment is reversed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different method:

```
home_price_gotten = False

while not home_price_gotten:
    try:
        home_price = input('Enter the price of your dream house\n')
        home_price = int(home_price)
        if home_price < 1:
            raise TypeError
        home_price_gotten = True
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Home price must be a number, but '{}' is not.".format(home_price))
    except TypeError:
        print('Home price must be a positive number')


print("Success! Home price is : '{}'".format(home_price))
```

Basically, until the user has given a valid home price, the loop will ask him for one, and try to convert his input to a number. If it fails, it's probably because the input is not a number. If it's smaller than 1, it raises another error. So you're covered.

BTW, this works in python 3 only. For python 2, swap `input()` for `raw_input()`

Comment: Yeah, thanks i figured it out it was that my python version was wrong.